When using AES, is doing encryption followed by decryption with the same key efficient?
It seems that rekeying between block cipher calls of AES is expensive. Meaning that calling $AESenc(K_1,M_1)$ and then calling $AESenc(K_2,M_2)$ with $K_1 \ne K_2$ is slower than calling $AESenc(K_1,M_1)$ and then calling $AESenc(K_1,M_2)$.
Is there a penalty cost for doing encryption and then decryption with the same key compared with two times encryption with the same key? Meaning is calling $AESenc(K_1,M_1)$ and then calling $AESdec(K_1,M_2)$ slower than calling $AESenc(K_1,M_1)$ and then calling $AESenc(K_1,M_2)$?
I am assuming that using the instructions AES-NI is possible and you compare the fastest implementations for each.


Is there a penalty cost by doing encryption and then decryption with the same key compared with two times encryption with the same key?.... I am assuming that using the instructions AES-NI is possible and you compare the fastest implementations for each.

No, there is not. If you look at the AES-NI a sample code for encrypt and decrypt, you will see that the key schedule call is the same ( by definition AES decryption uses generated keys in reverse). The keys are generated (AESKEYGENASSIST), and then used forward in encryption and backward in the decryption.
If you don't clear the expanded key, it is there, then you can use it for encryption and decryption.
The key schedule is not a problem for comparing fasted implementation as long as you are not comparing very short messages. The key schedule is calculated only once, for long messages it will not be a performance issue.
